# How show conditional sum using multiple dataset?

Tags: reportviewer

I need show on my reportviewer the conditional sum getting data of other dataset, because my report show data of multiples dataset.

=Sum(iif(Fields!Id.Value = Parameters!Id.Value, Fields!Jan.Value,""),"Other_DataSet")

This code below works fine. But use default dataset, setted on bind propertie.
=Sum(iif(Fields!Id.Value = Parameters!Id.Value, Fields!Jan.Value,""))

Answer (score 0):

This would be solved by using the Lookup function.

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Id.Value = Parameters!Jan.Value, LOOKUP(Fields!Id.Value, Fields!MatchingKeyIn2ndDataset.Value, Fields!ValueToReturn.Value, "Other_Dataset"), 0)